# C# Post data set to null when indexes do not start at zero

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, post

I have a dynamic form that has a list of SKUs that looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%=data.value%>" name="SkuAliases[<%=data.i%>].SKU" />
```

When I post this and the indexes of `SkuAliases[]` start with zero all works great I can loop through each `SkuAlias` without hiccup.

Once I delete say the row with the zero index the `SkuAliases` Property is `null` on my model and all validation fails along with anything else I want to do with this data.

How can I keep the `SkuAliases` `List` populated regardless of index numbers?

**Model**

```
public class Model
{
    public PickboxModel()
    {
        this.SkuAliases = new List<SkuAliasModel>();
    }

    ...
    public List<SkuAliasModel> SkuAliases { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public string Create(Model model)
{
    if (model.SkuAliases != null)
    {
        foreach(var sku in model.SkuAliases)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also had same issue, what I was done is regenerate the hidden fields using jQuery on submit base on the remaining rows.

Comment: That actually what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working by regenerating the hidden field indexes like so after one was deleted.

```
var aliases = $('input[type=hidden]');
for(var i = 0, t = aliases.length; i < t; i++)
{
    aliases[i].name = aliases[i].name.replace(/(\[\d+\])/g, "["+i+"]");
}
```

Obviously not this dumbed down but this is just to illustrate the solution.